# Compiling/Running Issues with C++ in Visual Studio, CodeBlocks, and Eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2015, codeblocks

I wrote some code for a new assignment I got for a class, and noticed that whenever I tried to debug it, it would freeze Visual Studio 2015 completely.

I tried the code in CodeBlocks, and it just puts up a blank command prompt.

I tried the code in Eclipse and it just gets stuck trying to run it.

Opening the executable by itself creates a process that I can't terminate.

Now, whenever I try and write a simple "Hello World" program, this freezes Visual Studio and Codeblocks as well. What do I do? This assignment is due tomorrow and I can't debug or run the program without my IDEs freezing completely.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

   cout << "Hello World" << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

causes Visual Studio 2015 to freeze.

Comment: At what point does it freeze? When you type, compile, run?

Comment: @NeilKirk I'm on Windows 10, I'll click Local Windows Debugger at the top and it'll just give me the spinning loading cursor forever. It's set as a Win 32 Console Application.

Comment: @Koronakesh Try setting it up as an empty project and add a source file with the code you have above.That might fix your issues.

Comment: @user3147395 No luck. It builds it and freezes.

Comment: @Koronakesh Can you build/compile it without running it?

Comment: @user3147395 Yes, however, opening the executable this produces outside of Visual Studio has the same result. Infinite spinning cursor.

Comment: @Koronakesh Sounds like an issue with the compiler or maybe an anti-virus program preventing the opening of unknown .exe files. Sorry, I can't be of more help.

Answer (score 0):

this sounds like a virus in your system or a conflict between the Compilers (two or more) running at the same time! Reboot the machine and just try to run it only one once if not reboot again and the try the 2nd compiler..and so on..if nothing helps... download a free antivirus (or buy one) to check your system!